# How to implement model validation on autocomplete field in yii2?

Tags: validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using a jui autocomplete widget in my form. Model validation is not working properly in here.

This is my view

```
<?php $form  = ActiveForm::begin();?>
<div class="members-form">

<div class="col-md-5">




                <?php
                $data = FamilyName::find()
                ->select(['name as value', 'name as  label','id as id'])
                ->asArray()
                ->all();

                echo 'Family Name' .'<br>';
                echo AutoComplete::widget([
                     'name' => 'family',    
                     'id' => 'family_name',
                     'clientOptions' => [
                        'source' => $data,
                        // 'minLength'=>'3', 
                        'autoFill'=>true,
                        'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                        $('#members-family_name_id').val(ui.item.id);//#City-state_name is the id of hiddenInput.
                     }")],
                     ]);
                ?>

                <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'family_name_id')?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'remarks')->textInput() ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

my model code

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['family_name_id', 'first_name',
            'date_of_birth', 'relation_id', 'is_head','marital_status','remarks',
            'gender','address_id'], 'required'],

        ];
    }
```

Now if i try to create a new member with no data selected in any of the fields, then required fields will show like " ... cannot be blank" in red. But the family_name_id is not showing such validation. The data is not getting saved if leave the auto complete field empty but no validation message is being displayed. How can i show validation messages with jui auto complete ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you faced the same problem as I had few weeks ago. I experienced similar behavior: I saw autocomplete suggestions and could interact with them, but when I left the input field the client-site validation kept silent.

If you look at the html produced by your view, at the bottom you can see some javascript code, which is responsible for the client-side validation. It looks like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  
....

jQuery('#app-new-form').yiiActiveForm(
[
{
"id":"application-familyname",
"name":" familyname ",
"container":".field-application-familyname",
"input":"#application-familyname",
"enableAjaxValidation":true,
"validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
  
     yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Field cannot be empty"});
            }
}
], []);


.....

});
```

This code assigns an event handler to your autocomplete field to start the client-side validation. But you have to pay attention, which id is used for the field. Unfortunately, yii2 takes the id provided by you only to construct the `<input>` element in html. When it produces javascript code the id is always generated from few permanent parts. The most important two are the name of the model and the name of the attribute. In your case id should be something like 'your_modelname -family_name_id'.

Because your explanation is not complete, this is only a guess. So, look at your html source and be sure you have the same id for the input you try to validate and the id in the JavaScript (see above).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Html Hidden Input .. You have to use ActiveForm HiddenInput to show error validation..

use

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'family_name_id')->hiddenInput()->label(false);>
```

Comment: i tried but still not showing validation error messages

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `family_name_id` instead of creating a new select?

```
<?= $form->field($model, "family_name_id")->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(FamilyName::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    ['prompt' => 'Select']
) ?>
```

And you can change the label by using `->label('Family Name')`, but i would recommend changing in model (unless you need "Family Name Id" as a label elsewhere).

I know you didn't said anything about that, but can i recommend you to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004550/should-i-calling-model-direct-from-view-yii2/34005246#34005246) about using methods that perform sql queries inside your view?